# Sequel Pro "SSH port forwarding failed"

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh

When I try to connect to MySQL via Sequel Pro SSH I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to host a.fcknet.dk because the port connection via SSH was refused.
>
> Please ensure that your MySQL host is set up to allow TCP/IP connections (no --skip-networking) and is configured to allow connections from the host you are tunnelling via.
>
> You may also want to check the port is correct and that you have the necessary privileges.
>
> Checking the error detail will show the SSH debug log which may provide more details.
>
> MySQL said: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

I checked my `my.cnf`, and the following section existed:

```
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

I am able to successfully connect through SSH and then manually connecting to the MySQL server via the `mysql`command. How do I make this work? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken here but I think that if MySQL binds to the localhost it only listens via a socket, so it will not be connectable via localhost:3306 (which is how the tunnelling will work).

Test this by trying to telnet to it: `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`